# VTK file not loaded in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, vtk

I have a three dimensional data stored in a VTK file. I have no trouble opening this file in any 3D viewer applications (e.g. Paraview). I want to show my file using ThreeJS package.

I noticed that ThreeJS VTK support is limited to PolyData encoded in ASCII format. So I exported my data following this format (still readable in Paraview and other 3D viewers). I used a ThreeJS example [here](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=vtk#webgl_loader_vtk) to open VTK files. It opens the Bunny.vtk file properly, but doesn't show my data:

```js
                var loader = new VTKLoader();
                loader.load( "./data.vtk", function ( geometry ) {

                    geometry.center();
                    geometry.computeVertexNormals();

                    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                    mymesh = mesh;
                    // mesh.position.set( - 0.075, 0.005, 0 );
                    // I tried with and without the following scaler
                    mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.00001 );
                    console.log(mesh);
                    scene.add( mesh );

                } );
```

The header of Bunny.vtk example file that works with this code:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 35947 float
-0.0378297 0.12794 0.00447467 -0.0447794 0.128887 0.00190497 -0.0680095 0.151244 0.0371953 
-0.00228741 0.13015 0.0232201 -0.0226054 0.126675 0.00715587 -0.0251078 0.125921 0.00624226 
-0.0371209 0.127449 0.0017956 0.033213 0.112692 0.0276861 0.0380425 0.109755 0.0161689
```

The header of my Data.vtk file that doesn't work:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 4.2
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 80851 double
-2570 -1280 -1075.24966 -2570 -1280 -435.24966 -2570 -1280 204.75034 
-1930 -1280 -1075.24966 -2570 -640 -1075.24966 -1930 -1280 -435.24966
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing `Data.vtk` in this thread?

Comment: @Mugen87 Thanks for your reply Mugen. But since the vtk file is for a private company, I am now allowed to share it. However, the following lines after those headers, are numbers only

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: @TheJim01 I get no errors. I just see the pure black background with no data visible

Comment: We'll need more info, like how you're setting up your camera. The model might be out of the depth range of the camera. Or maybe it's simply too small (`0.00001` is quite the scaling factor...). Or maybe you're inside the mesh, and you can't tell because your material isn't set to `DoubleSide`. Or, potentially, the data is bad, and the face/vertex normals are inverted and causing the faces to shade black. There are a lot of reasons why the model might be loading correctly, yet isn't showing up.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thanks for your reply. I tried many ideas you mentioned but still having problem.

Comment: @Mugen87 You can have access to the file in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vAm7yfWILsbs3NP4YlwUwqaYyW5PHQIH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Um, maybe the loader can't handle the version 4.2. The bunny file from the repository has a lower version.